# setAttribute onClick with a variable as parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, onclick, setattribute

Is this possible? And if so, how?¨
Is it possible to setAttribute onclick=myFunction() with a variable as parameter?

```
var variableCross = localStorage.getItem('cross'+localStorage.getItem('number'));
del.setAttribute("onClick","myFunction(variableCross);");
```

myFunction(variableCross); sends variable like a string? doesn't it?

thx

Comment: Do you know the name of the JS variable at the time you are adding this attribute?

Comment: Did you try myFunction(cross)  ?

Comment: do not set events with setAttribute!

Comment: and how to do it if i shouldn't set events with setAttribute?

Comment: Create a global variable inside the javascript scope, and reference the variable inside the function. if you need the value. del.setAttribute("onClick","myFunction("+VARIABLE+");");

Comment: @Djavier89 i did as you said but i got null back when i alert the variable in myFunction

Comment: @maček del is:var del = document.createElement("img");

Comment: @Dwadelfri, I've added an answer now that we have more information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming this bit of code does what you want

```
var variableCross = localStorage.getItem('cross'+localStorage.getItem('number'));
```

Then this should work for you

```
del.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  myFunction(variableCross);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -3):

You retrieve you local storage values and pass them as string to you function by simply:

```
    this.getElementById('button1').setAttribute("onClick","alert("+variableCross.toString()+");");
```

here is the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZyDL4/